# inclusion $\Bbb R \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ is an injective morphism but not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I am trying to understand this statement in my course:

inclusion $i:\Bbb R \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ is an injective morphism but not a homeomorphism.

Before I try to prove it is not a homeomorphism, I don't understand why it is injective:

We have $\Bbb R\cong \Bbb R \times \{1\}$, so for instance :
$i(5) = i(5,1) = 0$ and $i(1) = i(1,1) = 0$.

Am I missing something?

Thank you for your hints and comments.

Comment: It is not injective. I believe they meant $i:\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}$ diagonally, that is $1\mapsto (1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you! that's what I thought, it must be a typo.

Comment: There is a famous map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ which is continuous and injective. But it is not the inclusion map.

Comment: Thank you!, could you explicit this map?

Comment: @CaveJohnson It could as well be that. For the OP I'll mention that the map is given by $x\mapsto (ax+\mathbb{Z},bx+\mathbb{Z})$ where $1,a,b$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. An important property of this map, besides being continuous and injective is that the image is a proper dense subgroup of the torus.

Comment: That makes sense as an injective map thank you!

Comment: Ok, so the wording is very bad because $\mathbb{R}$ formally is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2/\sim$ for any relation $\sim$. It is not even a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So $i$ being "inclusion" simply doesn't make sense. So what exactly is the definition of $i$? And what do you mean by $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$? The quotient group? The collapse?

Comment: Are there online notes for this course? If so, could you link to them with a page reference to where the problematic statement is?

Comment: @freakish I guess $\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ is the quotient group. What is the collapse?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma unfortunately it is from my course on Lie groups and I have no online reference. and I litteraly gived the statement from my course (printed version)

Comment: @PerelMan If $X$ is a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ then sometimes we use $X/A$ to denote $X/\sim$ where $a\sim b$ iff $a=b$ or $a,b\in A$. This is also known as collapsing $A$ to a point and is very different from quotient group, e.g $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite bouquet of circles under this definition. While the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is just a single circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is not precise, because there is no canonical inclusion of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$.

However, there are different natural ways to define an application $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$.
$$$$
1) The first one is, as you do, to define an application $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ by
$$f(x) = \overline{(x,1)}$$

(where $\overline{(a,b)}$ denotes here the canonical projection of $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$).

This is obviously not injective because $f(x+1) = \overline{(x+1,1)} = \overline{(x,1)} = f(x)$.
$$$$
2) Rather than imbedding $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the map $x \mapsto (x,1)$, you can also see $\mathbb{R}$ as a straight line with a non-zero slope. Consider the application from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $x \mapsto (x,ax)$. Let's see if the induced application $f_a : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ defined by
$$f_a(x) = \overline{(x,ax)}$$

is injective or not.

First you can see that if $a= \frac{p}{q}$ is rational ($p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$), $f_a$ is not injective. Indeed, one has
$$f(0) = \overline{(0,0)} = \overline{(q,p)} = \overline{\left(q, \frac{p}{q} \times q\right)} = f(q)$$

But you can see that is $a$ is irrational, then $f_a$ is injective. Indeed, if $f$ is not injective, then there exists $x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_a(x)=f_a(y)$, i.e. such that there exists $(p,q) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that 
$$(x,ax) = (y + q,ay + p)$$
You deduce that $x-y = q \neq 0$, and therefore $aq = p$, so $a$ is rational.

$$$$
3) Finally, you can prove that in the case where $a$ is irrational (and therefore $f_a$ is injective, $f_a$ is not a homeomorphism. There are several wyas to see that : you can for example see that the image of $\mathbb{R}$ by $f_a$ is not closed (in fact it is dense into $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$). I let you think about this.

Comment: I see! for the 3) is it because the only closed, dense set in a topological space is the space itself?

Comment: Yes ! You can prove "by hand" that $f_a(\mathbb{R})$ is dense (by approaching each point of $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ by points of $f_a(\mathbb{R})$), and check that $f_a(\mathbb{R})$ is not equal to  $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$. Then as you say, it cannot be closed.